# ggplot: iterating through geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a melted data set which looks like this:

```
> data
    total.id variable     value
1       2.2        44 0.0000000
2     2.4-T1       44 0.5000000
3       3.3        44 0.8000000
4     5.2-T1       44 0.1000000
5       2.2        48 0.3000000
6     2.4-T1       48 0.9000000
7       3.3        48 0.9000000
8     5.2-T1       48 0.7000000
```

...

And I am plotting the data like so:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=total.id)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I would like to link up each point which has the same 'total.id'- i.e. obtain a superposition of lines like this:

[image]

I've tried to use:

```
geom_line(data = subset(data, total.id %in% all.ids), aes(group = 1), legend = FALSE)
```

With `all.ids <- c(data$total.id)`

Without success- this links up all the points together.

[image]

Your help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All points get connected because you set `group` to a constant. Instead, map it to your variable:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=total.id, group=total.id)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Alternatively, you can use `geom_path`.